# Filling table using other 2 and checking for value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am completely new to SQL, and I need to create script, which will move some different columns values from 2 tables to another one. So, I have table translations:

```
id merchant_id lang_id is_default is_active
1  1           5       1          0
2  2           2       0          0
```

Table footers:

```
id is_active merchant_id footer_text
1  1         1           <p>text</p>
2  1         2           <p>hello</p>
```

And table footer_texts:

```
id footer_id lang_id footer_text
```

So I need to move all values of columns `id` and `footer_text`  from table `footers` to columns `footer_id` and `footer_text` of table `footer_texts` and value of `lang_id` of table `translations` to `lang_id` of `footer_texts` if `is_default` for it is 1 and `merchant_id` of tables `translations` and `footers` are equal. If there is no default, then there should be just 1.

Example of result:

```
id footer_id lang_id footer_text
1  1         5       <p>text</p>
2  2         1       <p>hello</p>
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Read something about JOIN.

Comment: @Akina okay, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following query

**note**: I defined the id column of the footer_texts table AUTO_INCREMENT.

```
INSERT INTO footer_texts(footer_id,lang_id,footer_text)
SELECT f.id as footer_id,IFNULL(t.lang_id,1),f.footer_text
FROM footers f LEFT JOIN translations t ON f.merchant_id = t.merchant_id and t.is_default = 1
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e91a55cb457a923aacbaa88f72ca033c)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I was trying using case and if else statements, but you have done this that easy, omg

Comment: You should use the simplest methods you can.